# SciPy UnivariateSpline Specifying Axis?

Tags: numpy, scipy, interpolation, spline

Using `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` it is possible to pass in a (1080, 4) nd.array and compute an interpolation function for each 'row' in a single command:

```
spline = interp1d(np.arange(1,5), np.random.random(1080,4), kind='cubic')
```

I am getting slightly different interpolation results (off the knots) than some existing Fortran code.  I believe this is because the SciPy source is using a b-spline and the Fortran code is using splines derived from numerical recipes.

I am attempting to perform the same interpolation using UnivariateSpline with `s=0`, so InterpolatedUnivariateSpline.

I am able to get this working if I pass the data row by row, i.e. using an iterator to step over all 1080 rows - this is highly inefficient.

Using:

```
spline = UnivariateSpline(np.arange(1,5).reshape(-1,1), np.random.random(1080,4), s=0, k=3)
```

I am seeing:

```
failed in converting 2nd argument `y' of dfitpack.fpcurf0 to C/Fortran array
```

I believe this is an issue getting the multi-dimensional array into Fitpack?  Any insight in how to avoid an iterator?  Additionally, any insight into a SciPy interpolation function that matches the one described in numerical recipes ([section 3.3, p.120](http://www.nrbook.com/empanel/)) - You have to type the page number, I can not direct link, it is a Flash viewer...

Comment: have you tried using `splmake`/`spleval`? `splmake` will accept a multidimensional array of y-values.

Answer (score 0):

In older version of SciPy (I observed it in 0.14) the splines returned by interp1d were of relatively poor quality. In versions 0.19  and later, `interp1d` is consistent with other spline routines, and since it accepts vector inputs, I think that answers the question. Here is the comparison of three spline constructors: the latter two only take one row as input.

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d, UnivariateSpline, splrep, splev
x = np.arange(1, 5)
y = np.random.normal(size=(1080, 4))
spl1 = interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')
spl2 = UnivariateSpline(x, y[123, :], s=0, k=3)
spl3 = splrep(x, y[123, :], s=0, k=3)

t = 2.345
print(spl1(t)[123], spl2(t), splev(t, spl3))
```

This prints (with my random numbers)

```
-0.333973049011 -0.333973049011 -0.333973049011
```